# MVC Solution is set to US Date format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a MVC 5 web application within Visual Studio 2013, where I am having trouble with the date format. When I run the code, the date format is returning in US `Datetime abc = DateTime.Now;` equals "05/19/2014 00:00:00" where I would like it to return in the UK format.

My language and region settings on my local machine are set to UK format and my location is set to UK as well.

The project is setup in Team Foundation Server and there are three other developers working on this project. All project files have been checked in and synchronized.

But the other developers are returning the UK Date format.

I have created another testing project and it returns the date is the UK format. So I know that is not my Visual Studio settings.

Does anyone know where I can check or change any setting or code where I can return the date format of my local machine.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can read Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
That's how I implemented multiple languages in a given site change those values at runtime to the locale you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to `enableClientBasedCulture` in your `Web.Config`:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set following cultures;

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

also make sure the input mask in your interface is set currectly so it return what your backend expects.

Comment: Generally it is better to configure this using Web.config instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: Will  try this next time :) was not aware this is possible

Answer (score 0):

```
Datetime abc = DateTime.Now;
```

The above code has absolutely nothing to do with how a date or time is represented. All a DateTime object does is keep track of the number of ticks since some specific date. **Only** when you convert it to a string does any sort of formatting matter.

See [Custom Date and Time format strings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Formatting is influenced by properties of the current
>   DateTimeFormatInfo object, which is provided implicitly by the current
>   thread culture or explicitly by the IFormatProvider parameter of the
>   method that invokes formatting. For the IFormatProvider parameter, you
>   should specify a CultureInfo object, which represents a culture, or a
>   DateTimeFormatInfo object.